# Proving a criterion for flatness of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, category-theory, tensor-products

I am following Qing Liu's textbook "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves," and have come upon the following statement (the truth of which is well-known):

**Theorem**: Let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then $M$ is flat if and only if for every ideal $I$ of $A$, the canonical homomorphism $I \otimes_A M \rightarrow IM$ is an isomorphism.

The proof goes as follows: first, Liu shows it for free modules of finite rank, then for free modules of arbitrary rank, then finally for general modules. The first two parts of the proof I have no trouble with. However, I am struggling to understand the justification for the final step. Here is how the proof goes:

Let $N$ be an arbitrary $A$-module, and suppose we have an injective map $N' \rightarrow N$. There exists a free $A$-module $L$ and a surjective homomorphism $p \colon L \rightarrow N$. Set $L' = p^{-1}(N')$. We have a commutative diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\ker p @>>> L' @>>> N' @>>> 0 \\
@| @VVV @VVV \\
\ker p @>>> L @>>> N @>>> 0
\end{CD}
whose horizontal lines are exact, whence...

This is where I am stuck; I don't understand why we have a map $\ker p \rightarrow L'$. The module that would go there such that the horizontal row is exact is $\ker[L' \rightarrow N']$, but this module in particular contains only elements of $L' \subseteq L$. It is easy to show that we can make the leftmost arrow (which is currently an equality) into an injection, but this does not help us since we are trying to prove that $M$ is flat. I do not see in general why $\ker [L' \rightarrow N'] \cong \ker [L \rightarrow N]$.

Comment: This also follows from the fact that [rows have the same kernels in a pullback square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113807/rows-have-the-same-kernel-in-a-pullback-square).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, $\ker p = p^{-1}(0) \subset p^{-1}(N') = L'$. The morphism $L' \longrightarrow N'$ is $p|_{L'}$. So $\ker [L' \longrightarrow N'] \subset \ker p$. Then $\ker p \subset L'$ implies $\ker [L' \longrightarrow N'] = \ker p$.

Comment: Thank you, I was being so silly!